# Scrollable image with pinch-to-zoom in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display an image in my React Native app (Android) and I want to give users an ability to zoom that image in and out.
This also requires the image to be scrollable once zoomed in.

How would I go about it?

I tried to use `ScrollView` to display a bigger image inside, but on Android it can either scroll vertically or horizontally, not both ways.
Even if that worked there is a problem of making `pinch-to-zoom` work.

As far as I understand I need to use `PanResponder` on a custom view to zoom an image and position it accordingly. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You can look out for Android pinch-to-zoom Image View libraries and map it to a react-native component.

Comment: I have the same problem, @Leonti, does you solve it?

Comment: @savelichalex yes, I had to write my own component, please see the answer

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own `ZoomableImage` component. So far it's been working out pretty well, here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, PanResponder, Image } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

function calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  const dx = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
  const dy = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(dx, 2) + Math.pow(dy, 2));
}

function calcCenter(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  function middle(p1, p2) {
return p1 > p2 ? p1 - (p1 - p2) / 2 : p2 - (p2 - p1) / 2;
  }

  return {
x: middle(x1, x2),
y: middle(y1, y2)
  };
}

function maxOffset(offset, windowDimension, imageDimension) {
  const max = windowDimension - imageDimension;
  if (max >= 0) {
return 0;
  }
  return offset < max ? max : offset;
}

function calcOffsetByZoom(width, height, imageWidth, imageHeight, zoom) {
  const xDiff = imageWidth * zoom - width;
  const yDiff = imageHeight * zoom - height;
  return {
left: -xDiff / 2,
top: -yDiff / 2
  };
}

class ZoomableImage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
super(props);

this._onLayout = this._onLayout.bind(this);

this.state = {
  zoom: null,
  minZoom: null,
  layoutKnown: false,
  isZooming: false,
  isMoving: false,
  initialDistance: null,
  initialX: null,
  initalY: null,
  offsetTop: 0,
  offsetLeft: 0,
  initialTop: 0,
  initialLeft: 0,
  initialTopWithoutZoom: 0,
  initialLeftWithoutZoom: 0,
  initialZoom: 1,
  top: 0,
  left: 0
};
  }

  processPinch(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
const distance = calcDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2);
const center = calcCenter(x1, y1, x2, y2);

if (!this.state.isZooming) {
  const offsetByZoom = calcOffsetByZoom(
    this.state.width,
    this.state.height,
    this.props.imageWidth,
    this.props.imageHeight,
    this.state.zoom
  );
  this.setState({
    isZooming: true,
    initialDistance: distance,
    initialX: center.x,
    initialY: center.y,
    initialTop: this.state.top,
    initialLeft: this.state.left,
    initialZoom: this.state.zoom,
    initialTopWithoutZoom: this.state.top - offsetByZoom.top,
    initialLeftWithoutZoom: this.state.left - offsetByZoom.left
  });
} else {
  const touchZoom = distance / this.state.initialDistance;
  const zoom =
    touchZoom * this.state.initialZoom > this.state.minZoom
      ? touchZoom * this.state.initialZoom
      : this.state.minZoom;

  const offsetByZoom = calcOffsetByZoom(
    this.state.width,
    this.state.height,
    this.props.imageWidth,
    this.props.imageHeight,
    zoom
  );
  const left =
    this.state.initialLeftWithoutZoom * touchZoom + offsetByZoom.left;
  const top =
    this.state.initialTopWithoutZoom * touchZoom + offsetByZoom.top;

  this.setState({
    zoom,
    left:
      left > 0
        ? 0
        : maxOffset(left, this.state.width, this.props.imageWidth * zoom),
    top:
      top > 0
        ? 0
        : maxOffset(top, this.state.height, this.props.imageHeight * zoom)
  });
}
  }

  processTouch(x, y) {
if (!this.state.isMoving) {
  this.setState({
    isMoving: true,
    initialX: x,
    initialY: y,
    initialTop: this.state.top,
    initialLeft: this.state.left
  });
} else {
  const left = this.state.initialLeft + x - this.state.initialX;
  const top = this.state.initialTop + y - this.state.initialY;

  this.setState({
    left:
      left > 0
        ? 0
        : maxOffset(
            left,
            this.state.width,
            this.props.imageWidth * this.state.zoom
          ),
    top:
      top > 0
        ? 0
        : maxOffset(
            top,
            this.state.height,
            this.props.imageHeight * this.state.zoom
          )
  });
}
  }

  _onLayout(event) {
const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;

if (
  layout.width === this.state.width &&
  layout.height === this.state.height
) {
  return;
}

const zoom = layout.width / this.props.imageWidth;

const offsetTop =
  layout.height > this.props.imageHeight * zoom
    ? (layout.height - this.props.imageHeight * zoom) / 2
    : 0;

this.setState({
  layoutKnown: true,
  width: layout.width,
  height: layout.height,
  zoom,
  offsetTop,
  minZoom: zoom
});
  }

  componentWillMount() {
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
  onPanResponderGrant: () => {},
  onPanResponderMove: evt => {
    const touches = evt.nativeEvent.touches;
    if (touches.length === 2) {
      this.processPinch(
        touches[0].pageX,
        touches[0].pageY,
        touches[1].pageX,
        touches[1].pageY
      );
    } else if (touches.length === 1 && !this.state.isZooming) {
      this.processTouch(touches[0].pageX, touches[0].pageY);
    }
  },

  onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true,
  onPanResponderRelease: () => {
    this.setState({
      isZooming: false,
      isMoving: false
    });
  },
  onPanResponderTerminate: () => {},
  onShouldBlockNativeResponder: () => true
});
  }

  render() {
return (
  <View
    style={this.props.style}
    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
    onLayout={this._onLayout}
  >
    <Image
      style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: this.state.offsetTop + this.state.top,
        left: this.state.offsetLeft + this.state.left,
        width: this.props.imageWidth * this.state.zoom,
        height: this.props.imageHeight * this.state.zoom
      }}
      source={this.props.source}
    />
  </View>
);
  }
}

ZoomableImage.propTypes = {
  imageWidth: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  imageHeight: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  source: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default ZoomableImage;
```

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you should make a Component on github from this and we (people) will improve that.

Comment: Hi, I was unable to make this answer work in latest RN 0.46 / Expo. For me `onPanResponderMove ` is never fired when there are 2 fingers on the image. Any idea? Can you publish an Expo/CRNA app which shows how to use your code correctly? According to this issue I'm not alone having the problem: https://github.com/stoffern/react-native-image-cropper/issues/8

Comment: Can anyone confirm this solution has ever worked? There's an feature request to support multi-touch in PanResponder: https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/panresponderonpanrespondermove-not-responding-for-pinch

Comment: It seems to work for me on Android only. It needed the width and height set on the wrapping View though, either specific values or 100%.

Comment: How to pass a imageWidth, imageHeight and source props.
I have tried like 
< ZoomableImage  source={require('./assets/images/play')}  imageWidth={100} imageHeight={100} />
but it is not working. Giving error as this.PropTypes.number required.

How to solve this??

Comment: For me it works, though interactions are close, but no cigar. @Nik Did you ```import PropTypes from 'prop-types';``` You need to import it from a separate package now and not like ```import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';``` from the main package

Comment: Hero!!! @Darío I've removed the 'isRequired' fields and it went smooth. Great component! Soo satisfying

Comment: I have the image appearing now but since it is a landscape image and I wish to display it in portrait mode I would like to start the image already zoomed in. I tried changing the initialZoom state attribute but to no avail. How can I do this?

Comment: It is working for me on iOS, also it is a great help to build my own to suit my needs

Comment: This looks great! How do you specify the image file location (either URL or local file path?) If anyone's managed to make it work, could you make a working demo as GitHub, Expo Snack or something? I'm trying to grasp how this might work in practice.

Comment: how to integrate it inside a ViewPager @Leonti

Comment: If it is not workign on Android, then instead of `<View style={this.props.style}` try `<View style={[this.props.sty`le, { width: '100%', height: '100%' }]}` i.e. just set the `height` and `width`. Rest you can adjust yourself.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks :) I am not sure if anyone else has done this yet, but I made a expo snack with this code, and converted it to typescript. If anyone wants to see how to implement it, [you can do so here](https://snack.expo.io/@jaaywags/zoomableimage). I am not sure if there is a way to zoom in expo. I could not figure it out. But I tested it on Android Emulator and it works.

Comment: ^ In regards to my previous comment, I ended up going with [this package](https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-viewer#readme). My implementation worked well, but not perfect. I wanted a way to make the image bigger, navigate around the scrolled image, and swipe to the next image. This solution did not have that but this GitHub I just linked does. FYI, it has a dependency by the same author. I tried that first by itself, and it was not what I wanted. This one I linked is much better.

Comment: @Jwags I tried to use the package that you've mentioned, but I was not able to remove the black background, so I have used [react-native-image-pan-zoom](https://github.com/ascoders/react-native-image-zoom), but now it does not scoll on Android(Images are inside a ScrollView component,  any suggestions please?)

Comment: @GeekDev First off, sorry for the potato quaity. I am on mobile. I will try to fix this tomorrow. Basically I have this. And inside the renderImage method is just a touchable opacity that onPress, sets the displayModal flag to true and imageIndex variable to the value of the pressed image. Inside the touchable opacity is an image element to display the image. https://pastebin.com/qZP95C21

Comment: @GeekDev I created an [expo snack](https://snack.expo.io/@jaaywags/react-native-image-viewer) demoing the package. Take a look. I think the main issue is you were using ScrollView instead of FlatList?

Comment: @Jwags Thanks for sharing, I have already tried your idea, but my project requirements are different. In my project, I have a home feed similar to Instagram, so the user should pinch-to-zoom from outside. Got any other suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

There's a much easier way now.
Just make a ScollView with `minimumZoomScale` and `maximumZoomScale`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView minimumZoomScale={1} maximumZoomScale={5} >
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll me plz</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>If you like</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scrolling down</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>What's the best</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Framework around?</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:80}}>React Native</Text>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

// skip these lines if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent(
  'AwesomeProject',
  () => IScrolledDownAndWhatHappenedNextShockedMe);
```

Comment: Agreed, doesnt work on Android. (Expo 28.0, RN 0.55.4)

Comment: minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale are supported only in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

[image]
[image]

In my case I have to add images inside Viewpager with Zoom functionality.

So I have used these two library.

```
import ViewPager from '@react-native-community/viewpager'
import PhotoView from 'react-native-photo-view-ex';
```

which you can install from.

```
npm i @react-native-community/viewpager
npm i react-native-photo-view-ex
```

So I have used this code.

```
class ResumeView extends React.Component {

    render() {
        preivewArray = this.props.showPreview.previewArray
        var pageViews = [];
        for (i = 0; i < preivewArray.length; i++) {
            pageViews.push(<View style={style.page}>

                <PhotoView
                    source={{ uri: preivewArray[i].filePath }}
                    minimumZoomScale={1}
                    maximumZoomScale={3}
                    // resizeMode='stretch'
                    style={{ width: a4_width, height: a4_height, alignSelf: 'center' }} />

            </View>);
        }

        return (
            <ViewPager
                onPageScroll={this.pageScroll}
                style={{ width: '100%', height: a4_height }}>
                {pageViews}
            </ViewPager>
        )
    }

    pageScroll = (event) => {
        console.log("onPageScroll")
    }

}
```

Comment: what's `previewArray`?

Comment: preivewArray array is , images array , with the key : filePath

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the [react-native-image-zoom-viewer](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-pinch-to-zoom-image/) or [react-native-image-pan-zoom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-pan-zoom) library for that. Using this libraries you don't have to code manually.

Comment: `react-native-image-zoom-viewer` is very stable and useful. I'm agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm i react-native-photo-view-ex
```

```js
import PhotoView from 'react-native-photo-view-ex';
```

```js
<PhotoView
    style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
    source={{ uri: this.state.filePath }} // you can supply any URL as well
    minimumZoomScale={1} // max value can be 1
    maximumZoomScale={2} // max value can be 3
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't go deep if you are working with `react-native` because things will go more and more complex as deep you go.

Give it a try...

```
npm i react-native-image-zoom-viewer --save
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-image-zoom-viewer
```

copy this code and put it in app.js and hit Run button.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import ImageViewer from 'react-native-image-zoom-viewer';
const image = [
  {
    url:
      'https://static8.depositphotos.com/1020341/896/i/950/depositphotos_8969502-stock-photo-human-face-with-cracked-texture.jpg',
  },
];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ImageViewer imageUrls={image} />
    </View>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: I tried same code in latest react-native app, but it's not zooming, Do I have to pass props for that?

Comment: Not working! Image not displayed. Only a black screen.

Comment: @cmcodes it works only with older versions on `react-native` and `react-native-image-zoom-viewer`.  I'll update my answer in a few days after rechecking this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Features like zoom, pan, tap/swipe to switch image using react-native-gesture-handler,react-native-reanimated. Perfectly and smoothly running on android/ios.

**USAGE**

```
      <ImageZoomPan
        uri={'https://picsum.photos/200/300'}
        activityIndicatorProps={{
          color: COLOR_SECONDARY,
        }}
        onInteractionStart={onInteractionStart}
        onInteractionEnd={onInteractionEnd}
        onLongPressActiveInteration={onPressIn}
        onLongPressEndInteration={onPressOut}
        onSwipeTapForNext={onSwipeTapForNext}
        onSwipeTapForPrev={onSwipeTapForPrev}
        minScale={0.8}
        onLoadEnd={start}
        resizeMode={isFullScreen ? 'cover' : 'contain'} //'stretch'
      />
```

**Image Zoom component**

```
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {ActivityIndicator,Dimensions, Image} from 'react-native';
import {
  LongPressGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandler,
  PinchGestureHandler,
  State,
  TapGestureHandler,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
  useAnimatedGestureHandler,
  useAnimatedStyle,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import styles from './styles';

const clamp = (value, min, max) => {
  'worklet';

  return Math.min(Math.max(min, value), max);
};

const noop = () => {};

const getDeviceWidth = () => {
  return Dimensions.get('window').width;
};


const AnimatedImage = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Image);

export default function ImageZoom({
  uri = '',
  minScale = 1,
  maxScale = 5,
  minPanPointers = 2,
  maxPanPointers = 2,
  isPanEnabled = true,
  isPinchEnabled = true,
  onLoadEnd = noop,
  onInteractionStart = noop,
  onInteractionEnd = noop,
  onPinchStart = noop,
  onPinchEnd = noop,
  onPanStart = noop,
  onPanEnd = noop,
  onLongPressActiveInteration = noop,
  onLongPressEndInteration = noop,
  onSwipeTapForNext = noop,
  onSwipeTapForPrev = noop,
  style = {},
  containerStyle = {},
  imageContainerStyle = {},
  activityIndicatorProps = {},
  renderLoader,
  resizeMode = 'cover',
  ...props
}) {
  const panRef = useRef();
  const pinchRef = useRef();

  const isInteracting = useRef(false);
  const isPanning = useRef(false);
  const isPinching = useRef(false);
  const doubleTapRef = useRef(null);

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    canInteract: false,
    centerX: 0,
    centerY: 0,
  });

  const {canInteract, centerX, centerY} = state;

  const scale = useSharedValue(1);
  const initialFocalX = useSharedValue(0);
  const initialFocalY = useSharedValue(0);
  const focalX = useSharedValue(0);
  const focalY = useSharedValue(0);
  const translateX = useSharedValue(0);
  const translateY = useSharedValue(0);

  const onInteractionStarted = () => {
    if (!isInteracting.current) {
      isInteracting.current = true;
      onInteractionStart();
    }
  };

  const onInteractionEnded = () => {
    if (isInteracting.current && !isPinching.current && !isPanning.current) {
      isInteracting.current = false;
      onInteractionEnd();
    }
  };

  const onPinchStarted = () => {
    onInteractionStarted();
    isPinching.current = true;
    onPinchStart();
  };

  const onPinchEnded = () => {
    isPinching.current = false;
    onPinchEnd();
    onInteractionEnded();
  };

  const onPanStarted = () => {
    onInteractionStarted();
    isPanning.current = true;
    onPanStart();
  };

  const onPanEnded = () => {
    isPanning.current = false;
    onPanEnd();
    onInteractionEnded();
  };

  const panHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onActive: event => {
      translateX.value = event.translationX;
      translateY.value = event.translationY;
    },
    onFinish: () => {
      translateX.value = withTiming(0);
      translateY.value = withTiming(0);
    },
  });

  const pinchHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: event => {
      initialFocalX.value = event.focalX;
      initialFocalY.value = event.focalY;
    },
    onActive: event => {
      // onStart: focalX & focalY result both to 0 on Android
      if (initialFocalX.value === 0 && initialFocalY.value === 0) {
        initialFocalX.value = event.focalX;
        initialFocalY.value = event.focalY;
      }
      scale.value = clamp(event.scale, minScale, maxScale);
      focalX.value = (centerX - initialFocalX.value) * (scale.value - 1);
      focalY.value = (centerY - initialFocalY.value) * (scale.value - 1);
    },
    onFinish: () => {
      scale.value = withTiming(1);
      focalX.value = withTiming(0);
      focalY.value = withTiming(0);
      initialFocalX.value = 0;
      initialFocalY.value = 0;
    },
  });

  const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
    transform: [
      {translateX: translateX.value},
      {translateY: translateY.value},
      {translateX: focalX.value},
      {translateY: focalY.value},
      {scale: scale.value},
    ],
  }));

  const onLayout = ({
    nativeEvent: {
      layout: {x, y, width, height},
    },
  }) => {
    setState(current => ({
      ...current,
      canInteract: true,
      centerX: x + width / 2,
      centerY: y + height / 2,
    }));
  };

  const onImageLoadEnd = () => {
    onLoadEnd();
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  const onLongPress = event => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
      onLongPressActiveInteration();
    }
    if (
      event.nativeEvent.state === State.END ||
      event.nativeEvent.state === State.CANCELLED
    ) {
      onLongPressEndInteration();
    }
  };

  const onSingleTapEvent = event => {
    let e = event.nativeEvent;
    if (e.state === State.ACTIVE) {
      if (e.x < getDeviceWidth() / 2) {
        onSwipeTapForPrev();
      } else {
        onSwipeTapForNext();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <PinchGestureHandler
      ref={pinchRef}
      simultaneousHandlers={[panRef]}
      onGestureEvent={pinchHandler}
      onActivated={onPinchStarted}
      onCancelled={onPinchEnded}
      onEnded={onPinchEnded}
      onFailed={onPinchEnded}
      enabled={isPinchEnabled && canInteract}>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.container, containerStyle]}>
        <PanGestureHandler
          ref={panRef}
          simultaneousHandlers={[pinchRef]}
          onGestureEvent={panHandler}
          onActivated={onPanStarted}
          onCancelled={onPanEnded}
          onEnded={onPanEnded}
          onFailed={onPanEnded}
          minPointers={minPanPointers}
          maxPointers={maxPanPointers}
          enabled={isPanEnabled && canInteract}>
          <Animated.View
            onLayout={onLayout}
            style={[styles.content, imageContainerStyle]}>
            <TapGestureHandler
              waitFor={doubleTapRef}
              onHandlerStateChange={onSingleTapEvent}>
              <TapGestureHandler
                ref={doubleTapRef}
                onHandlerStateChange={() => null}
                numberOfTaps={2}>
                <LongPressGestureHandler
                  onHandlerStateChange={onLongPress}
                  minDurationMs={800}>
                  <AnimatedImage
                    style={[styles.container, style, animatedStyle]}
                    source={{uri}}
                    resizeMode={resizeMode}
                    onLoadEnd={onImageLoadEnd}
                    {...props}
                  />
                </LongPressGestureHandler>
              </TapGestureHandler>
            </TapGestureHandler>
            {isLoading &&
              (renderLoader ? (
                renderLoader()
              ) : (
                <ActivityIndicator
                  size="large"
                  style={styles.loader}
                  color="dimgrey"
                  {...activityIndicatorProps}
                />
              ))}
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </Animated.View>
    </PinchGestureHandler>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar conditions when working on an App, with requirements that needed the maps (in image) with pins, and the pins were needed to be draggable flag based. Map was required to be zoomable.
Was using ScrollView with GestureDetector and PanResponder and was working smoothly in iOS, until I ran the android version, where it sucked.

Researched a bit and gave `npm i @openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view` a [try](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openspacelabs/react-native-zoomable-view).

Here's what I did.

```js
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          minHeight: mapContainerHeight,
        }}
      >
        <ReactNativeZoomableView
          maxZoom={9}
          minZoom={0.5}
          zoomStep={0}
          initialZoom={1}
          bindToBorders={true}
        >
          <Image
            source={{ uri: mapImage }}
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              resizeMode: 'contain',
              marginTop: 0,
            }}
          />
          {pins.map((pin, index) => (
            <Pin
              key={index}
              pinImage={pinImage}
              pin={pin}
              index={index}
              isDraggable={shouldBeDraggable}
              onPinLocationUpdate={handlePinLocationUpdate}
              onPress={handlePinPress}
            />
          ))}
        </ReactNativeZoomableView>
      </View>
```

And my Pin.jsx looked like this:

```js
const Pin = ({
  pin,
  isDraggable,
  index,
  pinImage,
  // scale,
  onPinLocationUpdate,
  onPress,
}) => {
  const pinSize = 15;

  const panResponder = useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => isDraggable,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => isDraggable,
      // onPanResponderGrant: (_, gestureState) => {
      //   // Find the pin at the current gesture location

      //   scale.value = 1; // Reset scale to 1 when pin is being dragged
      // },
      onPanResponderMove: (_, gestureState) => {
        // You can add some logic here to restrict movement if needed

        if (!pin) return;

        const newX = pin?.left + gestureState.dx;
        const newY = pin?.top + gestureState.dy;

        // Update the position of the dragged pin based on the gesture
        // gestureState.moveX and gestureState.moveY give the current coordinates
        // Adjust the position accordingly based on your requirements
        console.log(
          "Dragging pin:",
          pin?.name,
          newX,
          newY,
          // gestureState.moveX,
          // gestureState.moveY,
        );

        onPinLocationUpdate?.({ ...pin, top: newY, left: newX });
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (_, gestureState) => {
        // This will be called when the drag is released
        // You can get the final position from gestureState.moveX and gestureState.moveY
        // Adjust the position accordingly based on your requirements
        const { moveX, moveY, dx, dy } = gestureState;
        console.log("Pin released at:", dx, dy);
        // does nothing just logs at the moment as onPanResponderMove handles the necessity

      },
    }),
  ).current;

  if (!pin) return;

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pin: {
      opacity: 40,
      position: "absolute",
      left: `${(pin.left / 1000) * 100 - 2}%`, // as per your needs
      top: `${(pin.top / 1000) * 100 - 7}%`, // as per you needs
      width: pinSize,
      height: pinSize,
    },
  });

  return (
    <View key={index} style={styles.pin}>
      <Pressable
        onLongPress={() => onPress?.(pin)}
        onPress={() => onPress?.(pin)}
        hitSlop={5}>
        <View {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
          <SvgUri width="100%" height="100%" uri={pinImage} />
        </View>
      </Pressable>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Pin;
```

Hope, this give pointers to someone with similar requirements.