# Zoom and pan on View that contains Inputs over Image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to zoom and pan a View that contains inputs over an image.
The inputs must maintain it's position relative to the image, and be resized as well, both on Android and iOS.

I've tried to accomplish this using [react-native-view-editor](https://medium.com/@sscaff1/react-native-image-panning-zooming-832aef361c87#.1uph2lf7p), but the TextInput doesn't get zoomed in as the image does, it stays the same size relative to the screen:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ViewEditor
      imageHeight={width}
      imageWidth={width}
      imageContainerHeight={width}
      imageMask={this.mask}
      maskHeight={width}
      maskPadding={50}
      >
      {() => (
        <Image
          source={{ uri: this.state.image }}
          style={{ flex: 1}} >
          <View>
            <TextInput />
          </View>
        </Image>
      )}
    </ViewEditor>
  </View>
```

I also tried [react-native-photo-view](https://github.com/alwx/react-native-photo-view), but it doesn't allow a TextInput or any other element to be added and controlled with the image:

```
<PhotoView
  source={{ uri: this.state.image }}
  minimumZoomScale={1}
  maximumZoomScale={2}
  androidScaleType="fitCenter"
  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <TextInput /> // error
</PhotoView>
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I just tried using the component included in this question: [Scrollable image with pinch-to-zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368919/scrollable-image-with-pinch-to-zoom), but I had the same problem as my first try. I placed a TextInput inside the image tag like so:

```
<View
    style={this.props.style}
    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
    onLayout={this._onLayout}>
    <Image style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      top: this.state.offsetTop + this.state.top,
      left: this.state.offsetLeft + this.state.left,
      width: this.props.imageWidth * this.state.zoom,
      height: this.props.imageHeight * this.state.zoom
    }}
      source={this.props.source} >
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' }}>
        <TextInput style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' }} />
      </View>
    </Image>
  </View>
```

and the TextInput doesn't get zoomed in, it stays the same size relative to the screen, and not relative to the image scale.