# ReactNative ScrollView won't scroll or zoom

Tags: android, react-native, flexbox, android-scrollview

Using create-react-native-app, testing with an Android device. I'm trying to display a full screen photo in a scroll view. The image displays larger than my screen but I can neither scroll nor zoom.

```
export default function Photo({ filename }) {
  return (
    <ScrollView
      centerContent
      contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
      maximumZoomScale={2}
      minimumZoomScale={1}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Image style={{ flex: 1 }} source={{ uri: assetPath(filename) }} />
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

This component is rendered from a top level react-router `Route`:

```
  <NativeRouter>
    <AndroidBackButton>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Route path="/" exact component={PhotoListContainer} />
        <Route
          path="/photos/:filename"
          component={({ match }) => (
            <Photo filename={match.params.filename} />
          )}
        />
      </View>
    </AndroidBackButton>
  </NativeRouter>
```

In the examples I've seen, there's one notable difference: the `Image` element usually does not have any styles. But if I remove the style property, the image disappears altogether. I suspect at least part of my problem stems from not understanding flex and being new to RN, and that the solution is simple. Please help if you can!

Comment: Did you try adding `resizeMode="contain"` prop to the image?

Comment: Just tried it after reading your comment. This makes the image fit better on the screen better, so that you can see the whole thing. But it does not enable zooming.

Comment: Did you check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368919/scrollable-image-with-pinch-to-zoom/37449923

Comment: There's also this medium post too: https://medium.com/@mheavers/animating-zoom-in-react-native-scroll-view-16587b35a064

Comment: Thanks for the links. I had read the medium post, but the SO question you linked might be helpful. Much appreciated.

Comment: kind of unrelated comment/question... is `<AndroidBackButton>` working as expected for you?  i can't get it happening with the same setup you're using.

Comment: Yes. When render this button, my phone's back button take me back to the previous screen. However, I've ditched react-router-native in favor of react-navigation. Much better performance :)

Answer (score 1):

These properties, `minimumzoomscale` and `maximumzoomscale` only works for `IOS` not for `Android`

[Link to docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#minimumzoomscale)

Second thing is Scroll only available if your view is getting out of screen.