# React Native: How to display my image in fullscreen when tapped on?

Tags: react-native

so i currently have my image rendered on the screen. I am trying to implement a feature where when i press on the image it opens in full screen (in full screen i will be able to zoom in).

I am using `react-native-expo-image-cache` to initially load the image on the screen and tried using `react-native-image-zoom-viewer` to implement the full screen feature but it didnt work.

Here is my code:

```js
const IMAGES = [
  post.images[1] ? { url: post.images[1].url } : {}
];

const showSlider = () => {
  <Modal visible={true} transparent={true}>
    <ImageViewer imageUrls={IMAGES}/>
  </Modal>  
};

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={showSlider}
>
  <Image
    uri={post.images[1].url}
    tint="light"
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

currently when i tap on the image nothing happens.

Comment: Use Screen width and height to set in Image style tag i will auto cover you whole screen

Comment: @WaleedNasir what i am trying to accomplish is that when i press on an image, it opens the image in fullscreen where i can then close and continue where i was.

Comment: @kd12345 You can onPress open a full screen Modal and put the image there

Comment: @GiladShnoor thank you for getting back to me. and in the full screen modal how do i implement the zoom in feature?

Comment: @kd12345 take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368919/scrollable-image-with-pinch-to-zoom-in-react-native it has a few suggestions for modules you can use for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
export default class Main extends Component {
  const IMAGES = [...];

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
  };

  showSlider() {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.showSlider()}>
          <Image uri={post.images[1].url} tint="light" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Modal
          visible={this.state.modalVisible}
          transparent={true}
          onRequestClose={() => this.setState({ modalVisible: false })}
        >
          <ImageViewer imageUrls={IMAGES} />
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nooruddin, thank you for getting back to me. i keep getting an error too many re-renders.

Comment: @kd12345 I have updated my answer on `onPress` check by doing that